# Filesize difference when cross compiling

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am writing a small application in c++ that runs on my host machine (linux x86) and on a a target machine(arm).
The problem I have is that on the host machine my binary is about 700kb of size but on the target machine it is about 7mb.
I am using the same compile switches for both platforms. My first though was that a library on the arget machine got linked statically but I checked both binaries with `objdump` and both use the same dynamically link libraries.
So can anyone give me hint how I can figure out why there is such a huge difference in size?

Comment: What is that application? How exactly are you compiling and linking it? What version of the compiler, of the linker.... Give us much more details....

Comment: Have you checked static vs dynamic linking?

Comment: What about stripped vs not-stripped binaries? If the ARM binary still has its debugging symbols it would be significantly larger. You could try stripping both binaries and see what happens...

Comment: @thkala: This seems to be the issue. If I strip my app afterwards the resulting binary on the arm is nearly at the same size. I think I need to double check the build system although I am sure that the `-g` option is not set.

Comment: @mkaes: let me turn this into an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While different computer architectures can *theoretically* require completely different amounts of executable code for the same program, a factor of 10 is not really expected among modern architectures. ARM and x86 may be different, but they are still designed in the same universe where memory and bandwidth is not something to waste, leading CPU designers to try to keep the executable code as tight as possible.

I would, therefore, look at the following possibilities, in order of probability:

- Symbol stripping: if one of the two binaries has been stripped from its symbols, then it would be significantly smaller, especially if compiled with debugging information. You might want to try to strip both binaries and see what happens.
- Static linking: I have occasionally encountered build systems for embedded targets that would prefer static linking over using shared libraries. Examining the library dependencies of each binary would probably detect this.
- Additional enabled code: The larger binary may have additional code enabled because e.g. the build system found an additional optional library or because the target platform requires specific handle.

  Still, a factor of 10 is probably too much for this, unless the smaller binary is missing a lot of functionality or the larger one has linked in some optional library statically.
- Different compiler configuration: You should not only look at the compiler options that *you* supply, but also at the defaults the compiler uses for each target. For example if the compiler has significantly higher inlining or loop unrolling limits in one architecture, the resulting executable could baloon-out noticeably.

Comment: I should have thought of the stripping myself. I did not figure out what is difference between my builds, but a post stripping of my executable is enough for it at the moment. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

first there is no reason to expect the same code compiled for different architectures to have any kind of relationship in size to each other.  You can easily have A be larger than B then change one line of code and then B is larger than A.

Second the "binaries" you are talking about are I am guessing elf, which is a little bit of binary and some to a lot of overhead.  The overhead can vary between architectures and other such things.

Bottom line if you are compiling the same code for two architectures/platforms or with different compilers or compile options for the same architecture there is no reason to expect the file sizes to have any relationship to each other.

Comment: Agreed, but I would expect a factor of 2 at most between x86 & ARM. A factor of 10 seems suspicious of different compilation/linling options

Answer (score 0):

Different architectures can have completely different ways to handle the same thing. For example loading immediate value on CISC (e.g. x86) architecture is usually one instruction, while on RISC (e.g. ppc, arm) it usually is more than one instruction, the actual number needed being dependent on the value. For example if the instruction set only allows 16bit immediate values, you may need up to 7 instructions to load a 64bit value (loading by 16bits and shifting in between the loads). Hence the code is inherently different.

Answer (score 0):

One reason not mentioned so far, but relevant to ARM/x86 comparisons is Floating Point emulation. All x86 chips today come with native FP support (and x86-64 even with SIMD FP support via SSE), but ARM CPU's often lack a FP unit. That in turn means even a simple FP addition has to be turned into a long sequence of integer operations on exponents and mantissa's.